# java.sql.Timestamp generates apace(s) between date and time .Must be replaced with %20 for good working on all PCs or devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service

I countered to a serious problem about android studio. I have a project working on a laptop and a pc in two places.Problem:When I work with PC in place of  1 , All my services in android is working but in the place of 2 (on laptop) all services except one in working. For this special service I got error code of 400 in place of 2. More information :**All services work fine in two places in the browser**.
all services use uniq connection string and ... and all services are in one dll located on host.I have this question Is any configuration is related with connection in android studio(and no in project) . I every time Copy all project From place of 1 to place of 2 and From place of 2 to place of one. Is  any body has a idea about my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Issue point is in space generated by java.sql.Timestamp(oDate). Output of this method generate a space between date and time.I don't know why  compiling in two machines have different results. When I get the stringurl value and pasting it in a browser , the browser converts the space to %20. I decided to replace this space with "%20" in my code when asigning of the urlstring . And I  solve the problem by using this string : (new java.sql.Timestamp(oDate)).replace(" ","%20").Thanks.